# Error when using dataloader command line

Tags: apex, data-loader

I have to upload some contacts to the salesforce database using the salesforce command line interface (CLIq). I downloaded the 23.0 beta version that works with dataloader 24 or higher. I haven't changed anything in either program (dataloader and CLIq) except the line you must uncomment to access the salesforce sandbox. I managed to log in and then when I write the simplest query it fires up an error. [image: error]

I tried googling the error but I didn't find any information about it. I need to use this command line because I need to make upserts into the database without manual interaction.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say it is calling the incorrect version of the partner API. As a result Salesforce is returning a SOAP message that doesn't have the expected schema. Which in turn causes the parser to fail.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2):

I also got this problem in order to solve this:

Use this in the cliq.properties file:

> sfdc.proxyPassword=
>   sfdc.endpoint=https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/**27**

This '27' is the DataLoader version you are using suppose I have version 27.0.1 so I put "27" here, this will solve your problem.

Thanks
Chirag